# Change default image of rich:pickList buttons

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

How do you change default images of  buttons? There is no such attribute and no options for that using facets. I've googled for a while and still did not find the solution. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: <f:facet name="copyControl">
        <h:commandButton image="path/to/image" />
    </f:facet>   does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Facets did not worked for me because I've tried to attach it to disabled button. So the solution:

```
<f:facet name="copyControl"> 
  <h:commandButton image="path/to/image" /> 
</f:facet>
```

works fine, BUT I still don't know how to attach image to disabled element

Answer (score 0):

My shame. It seems that the day was too hard:)

> Alternative to the given attributes are the following facets: 
>   "copyAllControl" , "removeAllControl" , "copyControl" , "removeControl" , >"copyAllControlDisabled" , "removeAllControlDisabled" , "copyControlDisabled" , >"removeControlDisabled" , "caption" .

I hope that would be helpful for someone